# What is the purpose of using a factory method in objective-c context?

Tags: objective-c, factory-method

What is the purpose of use of a factory method in objective-c context?

I am a bit confused about the use of factory methods in objective-c? What is the usefulness of doing so?

What is an example of using factory method in objective-c?

A bit confused. Any explanation would help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Objective-C does not have constructor methods that are available in other programming languages.  Factory methods are essentially Objective C's constructor methods.  They allow you to allocate memory for your object and initialize the values.

In your class, add methods with this pattern:

```
//Please follow Obj C naming conventions and name all init 
//methods "initWith" then desc
-(id)initWithString:(NSString*)str {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        _someProperty = str;
        _someOtherProperty = 0;
    } return self;
}

//Please follow Obj C naming conventions and name all factory 
//methods "myClassWith" then desc
+(instancetype)someClassWithString:(NSString*)str {
    return [[self alloc] initWithString: str];
}

//Pretty much every factory method should have a matching init method, and 
//only one init method should actually do the if(self = [super init] { /*do
//stuff*/ } return self;, the other init methods should call this one in some
//form or fashion
```

Then in main, you can do:

```
SomeClass *myVariableName = [SomeClass someClassWithString: 
    @"Init with me please"];
```

It saves you from having to do this:

```
SomeClass *myVariableName = [[SomeClass alloc] initWithString: 
    @"Init with me please"];
```

Or this:

```
SomeClass *myVariableName = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
[myVariableName mySetterMethod: @"Init with me please"];
[myVariableName setThatOtherProperty: 0];
```

Comment: Methods generally don't begin with uppercase letters, and you should drop the word `Initializer` from the name of your method. Also, `SomeClass` isn't a valid data type for an object, it would have to be `SomeClass *`.

Comment: You missed the return type for `someClassWithString:`, which these days should generally be `instancetype` rather than a hardcoded type like `SomeClass *`. For that matter, your code then sends `alloc` to `someClass` rather than `SomeClass`, which is also incorrect. Ideally, the receiver should be `[self class]` anyway, rather than a hard-coded class.

Comment: Also, don't use the word `init` as part of an argument name. `init` is the prefix for initializer methods; using it as a prefix for a variable or argument name adds nothing but potential confusion.

Comment: From **NSString.h**:  `+ (instancetype)stringWithString:(NSString *)string;`

Comment: `instancetype` has nothing to do with the method's implementation -- it's used by the compiler as data type information. But you should (as I pointed out earlier) consider using `[[[self class] alloc] init...]` rather than hard-coding the class. Otherwise the method won't work be able to produce instances of subclasses.

Comment: there is an error on the `+ init` should `- init`

Comment: if(self = [super init]) you should not do this as this will be warning from compiler, convenience initializer should not invoke init on super

Comment: @i.AsifNoor It won't be a warning from the compiler.  And it's not a convenience initializer.  In this case, it's the only initializer (and therefore cannot be convenience).  A convenience initializer should call to another initializer in the class... and in this case, there isn't one to call... because this isn't a convenience initializer.

Answer (score 10):

A factory method can be any class or instance method which returns a newly created and initialized object.

A "class factory method" in a more strict Objective-C context is any class method of a class *Class* whose name begins with *class*.., with its prefix stripped and first letter lowercased. Example for class `Foo`:

```
+(Foo*) fooWithParam:(NSDictionary*)param;
```

One reason to use *class* factory methods is for convenience. If you have a class `Foo` it may be created as follows in the usual way:

```
Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] initWithParam:param];
```

A convenient class factory method may now be used as this:

```
Foo* foo = [Foo fooWithParam:param];
```

However, there are other reasons where a class factory method is useful:

Suppose for example that the `initWithParam:` method can fail. Then there is much confusion about how this should be handled: should one throw an exception within init? Or should one return `nil`? There is controversy debate about the right approach in the community. Both approaches have subtle issues, including memory leaks which can not be avoided.

Thus, the most reasonable approach in such a case would be to use a class factory method with an error parameter. Here, you would get a Foo object as follows:

```
NSError* error;
Foo* foo = [Foo fooWithParam:param error:&error];
```

Now, the rule is:
If *foo* is nil, there was an error, and one can obtain detailed info about the error with the output parameter *error*:

```
if (foo) {
    ...
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Typically, the implementation would look as below:

```
+ (Foo*) fooWithParam:(NSDictionary*)param error:(NSError**error) {
    if ([param count] < 1) {
        // invalid parameters
        if (error) {                 
            NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Foo" code:-1000 userInfo: ...];            
        }
        return nil;
    }
    return [[self alloc] initWithParam:param]; // won't fail
}
```

---

Another reason is to implement "class clusters". That basically means that a class factory method returns a *subclass* of the class. An example is the `NSStream` class.

The `NSInputStream` class has a class factory method:

```
+ (id)inputStreamWithFileAtPath:(NSString *)path;
```

This returns a specialized class of `NSInputStream`.

---

In the pre-era of ARC there is an important detail:

Objects returned from a class factory method are 'autoreleased'. In other words, the client receiving the object does not own it - and thus does not need to release it.

Nowadays, with ARC these details became blurred: you do not need to release those objects manually anyway. How and when the object gets actually released is also subject to compiler optimizations.

Comment: Initializers that fail must return `nil` -- that's an API contract specified by Apple. Factory methods shouldn't take an error parameter. Please read Apple's documentation.

Comment: @jlehr The usual pattern is to return `nil`. However, there *can* arise subtle issues when handling an error within an init method - so that you can return `nil`. In certain cases you have to decide between a potential crash or a memory leak and possibly leaving the program in an invalid state when you want to return `nil`. Thus, throwing an exception wouldn't be that bad - with the intention the program terminates immediately. There have been lengthy discussions about this in the Cocoa mailing list and there is no clean solution.

Comment: @jlehr Methods which *can* fail, should have an error parameter. AFAIK, class factory methods aren't an exception. Can you please give a link where this is stated in the Apple docs?

Comment: When an `init...` method cannot initialize an object, it should:release the newly allocated object (in memory-managed code); return `nil`. [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html)

Comment: @jlehr Your donwn-vote is not justfied. I din't deny that, and where you point at  is common knowledge. I was merely pointing out that there *can* arise subtle issues *when* you do this, including crashes or memory leaks. This is where *class factory methods* can avoid this problem. And, where did the documentation state that class factory methods should not have an error parameter?

Comment: Doh, you're right of course...don't know what I was thinking. Unfortunately stackoverflow locked the vote -- can't change it unless the answer is edited.

Comment: @jlehr Did made an edit ;)

Comment: What I should have said is that it's not necessary (and fairly unusual) to provide an error parameter for a factory method that could potentially fail. See docs for `initWithContentsOfFile:` in numerous Foundation classes for examples. (`initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` of course being the exception that proves the rule.)

Comment: Apple is rarely providing error parameters, even when methods can fail and where it would make sense (for example creating a NSURL). It's even less usual to provide error parameters in init methods (and I wouldn't do it myself). I suspect, one reason for rarely providing error parameters is, that developers are more focussed on the "good" path, and rarely worry much about when something fails and what to do then. It's also quite cumbersome to setup an NSError objects and pass it through levels of methods. But I'm digressing... ;)

Comment: You can return nil and also populate an NSError pointer passed in.  Just saying...  And since as noted Apple does use an error param in some init methods, I don't see why an occasionally sprinkling should not also be OK for your own code.